# Designing a REST API for native mobile apps and browsers AS WELL AS 3rd parties OAuth2

Tags: api, rest, oauth-2.0

I have an idea for an application whose backend serves both native mobile apps and desktop browsers using OAuth2.

After reading the OAuth2 reference, I realized that I just needed to use a simple `Resource Owner Password Credentials Grant` because these clients aren't 3rd party clients. In other words, I'm just using OAuth2 as a simple login protocol that can serve both native mobile apps and the browser rather than using sessions for the browser and tokens for the apps (I'd rather keep it straightforward by using OAuth2's password grant).

However, I figure I'd want to release an API to the public for 3rd parties in the future. **How would I manage to serve 3rd parties as well as the mobile app and browser mentioned above?**

My main concern is that I'll end up with a server that has two different roles: One for 3rd parties and one for the mobile app and browser it directly supports. How should I go about doing this? I guess I can use a single `Authorization Code Grant`, and set apart 3rd party apps from the mobile/browser app, and the mobile/browser app will have full functionality by providing it with the entire scope resources from the API.

Answer (score 0):

If I would do what you have described, I would go with two API endpoints that might have similar functionalities but could serve the intended client in a more optimized way.

E.g rate limiting and other security aspects is very good to have early for 3rd parties, but might be a bit redundant for you internal clients.

Versioning and backwards compatibility could also be very different for your internal clients than your 3rd parties.

But, on the other hand, you could get a lot of benefits by dogfooding your own system and use the Oauth scopes.

It might be more of a philosophical architectural decision.
But in the long run I definitively see a good reason to separate internal API's from external due to the fact that the data might be different and the usage might diverge.